# Returning data from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know what is the best way of doing the following. I have created an object which makes use of Ajax. It is dependent on the returned data to generate form tags etc. The data is a record which is turned into array for the value I need (NAME/STATUS).

```
var HTMLFormTag = (function() {

    var selectList;

    var generateSelectHTML = function(data, keySameAsValue, addselectvalue, selectedValue){
        selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

        if(addselectvalue){
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", '');
            option.text = '--select--';
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }
        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
            var selected = '';
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            if(selectedValue.length > 0){
                if(value == selectedValue){
                    selected = 'selected';
                    option.setAttribute("selected", selected);
                }else{
                    selected = '';
                }
            }

            if(keySameAsValue){
                option.setAttribute("value", value);
            }else{
                option.setAttribute("value", index);
            }
            option.text = value;
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        });
    }

    return {
        createSelect : function(data,keySameAsValue, addselectvalue, selectedValue){
            generateSelectHTML(data,keySameAsValue, addselectvalue, selectedValue);
            return selectList;
        }
    }
})();


var CommsMatrix = (function() {

    // declare private variables and/or functions
    var statuses = [];
    var loadData = [];
    var protocols = [];

    var generateCMDStatuses = function() {
        loadData.push($.get( "/api/user/list/comms/matrix/data/format/json", {csrf: $.csrfParam('csrf'), select: 'distinct(status)' ,orderby: 'status'}).done(function(data){
            if (data.header.error) {
            } else {
                $.each(data.body.recordset.record, function( index, value ) {
                    if(value.STATUS != "to implement"){
                        statuses.push(value.STATUS);
                    }
                });

            }
        }));
    }

    var generateProtocolList = function() {
        loadData.push($.get( "/api/user/list/sys/list/protocols/format/json", {csrf: $.csrfParam('csrf'), orderby: 'name'}).done(function(data){
            if (data.header.error) {
            } else {
                $.each(data.body.recordset.record, function( index, value ) {
                    protocols.push(value.NAME);
                });

            }
        }));
    }

    return {
        createCM: function(params) {
              createCommsMatrix(params);
            },
        genCMDStatuses: function() {
            generateCMDStatuses();
        },
        genProtocolList: function() {
            generateProtocolList();
        },
        getCMDStatuses: function() {
            return statuses;
        },
        getSupportedProtocols: function() {
            return protocols;
        },
        getLoadData : function(){
            return loadData;
        }
    }

})();
```

In my main file to get the data I need:

```
$(function(){
    CommsMatrix.genCMDStatuses();
    CommsMatrix.genProtocolList();
    var loadData = CommsMatrix.getLoadData();
    var selectField = '';
    var selectProtocolField = '';

    t = $('table').DataTable( {
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching": false,
        }
    } );

    counter = 0;
    $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {

        var inputSrcField = '<input size="15" name="src['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';
        var inputDstField = '<input size="15" name="dst['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';
        var nattype = ['source','destination'];
        var selectNatField = HTMLFormTag.createSelect(nattype, true, true, '');
        selectNatField.setAttribute("name", 'nat['+counter+']');
        selectNatField = selectNatField.outerHTML;

        var inputNatField = '<input size="15" name="nat['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';

        var inputRemarksField = '<input name="remarks['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';
        var textareaSrcPort = '<textarea name="srcport['+counter+']">any</textarea>';
        var textareaDstPort = '<textarea name="dstport['+counter+']">any</textarea>';

        t.row.add( [
            selectField,
            inputSrcField,
            '',
            textareaSrcPort,
            inputDstField,
            '',
            textareaDstPort,
            selectNatField,
            inputNatField,
            selectProtocolField,
            inputRemarksField,
        ] ).draw( false );

        counter++;

    } );


    $.when(loadData[0],loadData[1]).done(function(data){
        var statuses = CommsMatrix.getCMDStatuses();
        selectField = HTMLFormTag.createSelect(statuses, true, false, 'To implement');
        selectField.setAttribute("name", 'status['+counter+']');
        selectField = selectField.outerHTML;

        var protocols = CommsMatrix.getSupportedProtocols();
        selectProtocolField = HTMLFormTag.createSelect(protocols, true, false, 'TCP');
        selectProtocolField.setAttribute("name", 'protocol['+counter+']');
        selectProtocolField = selectProtocolField.outerHTML;

        $('#addRow').click();
    });
});
```

Is this an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Google javascript promises and use them to return your async data.. alternatively you could use callback function.. however those kind of questions go on stack overflow and are off topic for code review.

Comment: I have updated my question and was told to post it on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710808/returning-data-from-javascript-object?noredirect=1#comment78389400_45710808

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - does this code work as is or not? If this code is fully functional and you just want to improve it then it belongs here. If it does not work yet it belongs on SO. Some of the StackExchange mods in general have been getting *really* bad at doing their jobs in the last year or so, so I wouldn't put it past someone to make a mistake.

Comment: the code works im looking for a way to do it better

Comment: I'm just reading on my phone so I'm not gonna post an answer but I think the biggest improvement you can make is to convert all the native JS stuff to jquery. For example, all the places you're creating elements and then setting attributes and adding to DOM can be done In a single line with jquery. Aside from that your code looks ok to me. Was there something specific you were concerned about?

Comment: I used the native JS because i saw somewhere its bench-marked to be way faster to create elements than using jquery. I wanted a way to do the ajax part a bit better. right now I have to run it then wait then get the data in a `when`. @Joseph answer may be something I am after

Comment: Everything native js is faster than jquery. If your concern is speed then drop jquery entirely. If your concern is maintainability then use jquery more. Just be consistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get( "/api/user/list/comms/matrix/data/format/json", {csrf: $.csrfParam('csrf'), select: 'distinct(status)' ,orderby: 'status'}).done(function(data){
```

Use the more standard promise interface that's available for jQuery AJAX functions. Instead of `done`/`fail`/`success`/`error`, use `then(successCb, failCb)`. Promises allow better flow control for async operations as well.

Even better, you can use the native `fetch` which is inspired by jQuery's ajax. It also returns a promise, albeit differently. It is always a success, you get the entire response (headers, body, etc.) and you decide what to do with it.

Speaking of promises...

```
$.when(loadData[0],loadData[1])
```

Native JS also has `Promise.all` which is also inspired by jQuery deferreds. It's like `$.when` except it accepts an array of promises instead of an args list of deferred objects. The resolved value of the promise returned by `Promise.all` is also an array of values resolved from the promises, in the order they were provided in the input array.

```
$(function(){
CommsMatrix.genCMDStatuses();
CommsMatrix.genProtocolList();
```

Instead of storing their deferred objects in an `loadData`, why not return their deferred objects, then feed them to `$.when`? Is there really a need to put it inside `loadData`? In fact, `statuses` and `protocols` are also the same thing.

Unless it's a cache of some sort, this intermediary array isn't necessary. Also, I'd leverage HTTP cache if you *are* doing caching. It's transparent to the code, so you don't do anything special (except for maybe ensuring headers are correct for caching and your request isn't busting the cache).

```
return {
    createCM: function(params) {
          createCommsMatrix(params);
        },
    genCMDStatuses: function() {
        generateCMDStatuses();
    },
    genProtocolList: function() {
        generateProtocolList();
    },
    getCMDStatuses: function() {
        return statuses;
    },
    getSupportedProtocols: function() {
        return protocols;
    },
    getLoadData : function(){
        return loadData;
    }
}
```

Whenever I see code like this, I cringe. Often times, this usually just translates to an object of functions. Skip the `return {...}` and the iife, and just use a straight-up object of functions instead.

```
    var inputSrcField = '<input size="15" name="src['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';
    var inputDstField = '<input size="15" name="dst['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';
    var nattype = ['source','destination'];
    var selectNatField = HTMLFormTag.createSelect(nattype, true, true, '');
    selectNatField.setAttribute("name", 'nat['+counter+']');
    selectNatField = selectNatField.outerHTML;

    var inputNatField = '<input size="15" name="nat['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';

    var inputRemarksField = '<input name="remarks['+counter+']" class="form-control"/>';
    var textareaSrcPort = '<textarea name="srcport['+counter+']">any</textarea>';
    var textareaDstPort = '<textarea name="dstport['+counter+']">any</textarea>';
```

You might want to consider using a template library for this, like Mustache.

So for instance, your query code could be simplified into:

```
const CommsMatrix = {
  getCMDStatuses: function(){
    return fetch('/api/user/list/comms/matrix/data/format/json', {
      body: URLSearchParams({ csrf: $.csrfParam('csrf'), select: 'distinct(status)', orderby: 'status' })
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.headers.error ? Promise.reject(response.headers.error) : response.json();
    }).then(body => {
      return body.recordset.record.map(v => v.STATUS)
    })
  },
  getSupportedProtocols: function(){
    return fetch('/api/user/list/sys/list/protocols/format/json', {
      body: new URLSearchParams({ csrf: $.csrfParam('csrf'), orderby: 'name' })
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.headers.error ? Promise.reject(response.headers.error) : response.json();
    }).then(body => {
      return body.recordset.record.map(v => v.NAME)
    })
  }
}

Promise.all([CommsMatrix.getCMDStatuses(), CommsMatrix.getSupportedProtocols()])
  // Destructuring the 2-item array into statuses and protocols variables
  .then(([ statuses, protocols ]) => {
    // You've got statuses and protocols loaded
  })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, im getting this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692554/url-query-string-in-fetch-api-in-javascript. `Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body`

Comment: I set the body to null to see how it works but then i get error in `Promise.all` part `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` around `.then(([ statuses, protocols ]) => {`

Comment: @shorif2000 For the first comment, `fetch` is fairly new. If you're using an older browser, that might be the cause. Refer to compatibility tables for details. There are also polyfills available in the wild. As for the latter, it's most likely your endpoint responded with HTML when fetch expected JSON. This usually happens when a JSON endpoint responds with an HTML error page. This is something your server should do consistently, and not for the JS to fix.

Comment: Sorry, had to downside for that one little comment about skipping the anon function and just using an object of functions. *That* kind of code makes me cringe. Plus the whole purpose of the iife is it allows for "private" methods and variables. You can't just swap one for the other in all cases.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. True, iife does allow "private" methods and variables. The net result is an object of functions in both cases (I declare a literal, OP's iife returns an object of functions). However, my suggestion holds no private members making an iife useless. No need to enforce a concept that's not needed. It only adds noise to the code.

Comment: @Joseph - You wouldn't use a `<font>` or a `<center>` in your markup, right? Those are semantically incorrect and should be done with CSS. Same reason you don't put CSS and JS in an HTML file. Semantically, *functional* code should go in a function, preferably avoiding literals entirely and using `prototype`. It's not just semantics though, it looks nicer. When I see a literal I expect data, not functions.

Comment: I will say the whole bit about the anonymous functions doing nothing but calling functions of the same name is a little.. redundant though.. i would have suggested ust renaming the functions if you had to do it like that.. `genProtocolList: generateProtocolList,`

Comment: @Joseph I realise fetch is hitting my SSO page which is returning html login page. this would not occur on a `$.get` as it checks the csrf to make sure it is valid. also noticed `fetch` is not an async call but a normal request. If I paste the url into my browser i get valid json on the screen but using the fetch hits my SSO

Comment: @Joseph i just saw IE 11 is not compatible with fetch so its not something i can use

Comment: @shorif2000 As mentioned in my [previous comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173153/returning-data-from-javascript-object/173211?noredirect=1#comment328614_173211), there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for it. And I'm not sure what you mean by "fetch is not an async call but a normal request". `fetch` [is asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Basic_concepts). What's probably missing are cookies, which `fetch` [omits and for you to explicitly supply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: @Joseph I have managed to get fetch working however i have cloned the fetch polyfill from github, included the fetch.js file after jquery but it is not working in IE11. Am i missing anything else?